Axios: Setting rejectUnauthorized to false using httpsAgent to ignore SSL issues doesn't work with POST requests
I'm using axios with NodeJS to query the REST API of Mikrotik RouterOS for that you need to use self-signed SSL certificates mandatorily.
It all works fine when i run GET requests  and add httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false})  .
But all other methods fail and I get this error:
cause: Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {
    code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
  }

i've already tried setting process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0; but with that it gives me a 401 HTTP code with "Unauthorized" message.
const macAddress= "10-78-D2-F9-12-E7";
const byPassed= "bypassed";


axios.post(`https://192.168.8.1:8082/rest/ip/hotspot/ip-binding`,
    {
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false}), // Allow Self-signed certificates
        auth: {
            username: "****",
            password: "*****"
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        content: JSON.stringify({
            "mac-address": macAddress,
            "type": byPassed,
            
        })
    },
    
    ).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });



Getting a 401 is progress! Your TLS is no longer rejecting the self-signed certificate. The 401 is indicating that the username and password are wrong

@JohnWilliams as i mentionned precedently  whith get, i got result but not whith post

The real problem was that I did a mistake with the axios syntax for post requests and that was the reason it wasn't working. So nothing to do with the httpAgent that was working after i fixed the syntax.
I also didn't need to set process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0;.
Find below the correct way to do it:
const macAddress= "10-78-D2-F9-12-E7";
const byPassed= "bypassed";


axios.post(`https://192.168.8.1:8082/rest/ip/hotspot/ip-binding`,
{
  "mac-address": macAddress,
  "type": byPassed,
}
{
   httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false}), // Allow Self- 
   signed certificates
        auth: {
            username: "****",
            password: "*****"
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
       
    },
    
    ).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });

